# .NET CSV Uploader Allow Nulls

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, csvhelper

I've put together a CSV importer which I assume works, though I get this error, how do I allow this column to be null so when it adds it to the table it automatically sets the ID? I've tried:

```
csv.Configuration.WillThrowOnMissingFields = false;
```

but it doesn't recognise it, this is the error I get when attempting to upload:

> CsvHelper.ValidationException: 'Header matching ['ID'] names at index 0 was not found. If you are expecting some headers to be missing and want to ignore this validation, set the configuration HeaderValidated to null. You can also change the functionality to do something else, like logging the issue.'

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("CreateBulk")]
    public ActionResult CreateBulkUpload()
    {
        object db;
        var file = Request.Files["attachmentcsv"];
        using (var csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(file.InputStream), true))
        {
            var records = csv.GetRecords<Client>().ToList();
            foreach (var item in records)
            {
                var strip = item.homePage.Replace("https://www.", "").Replace("http://www.", "")
                    .Replace("https://", "").Replace("http://", "").Replace("www.", "");

                string[] URLtests =
                    {"https://www." + strip, "http://www." + strip, "https://" + strip, "http://" + strip};

                string[] Metric = MajesticFunctions.MajesticChecker(URLtests);
                var userId = User.Identity.GetHashCode();
                var UserTableID = 1;

                var newclient = new Client

                {
                    clientN = item.clientN,
                    homePage = Metric[0],
                    clientEmail = item.clientEmail,
                    monthlyQuota = item.monthlyQuota,
                    TrustFlow = Int32.Parse(Metric[1]),
                    CitationFlow = Int32.Parse(Metric[2]),
                    RI = Int32.Parse(Metric[3]),
                    MJTopicsID = item.MJTopicsID,
                    UserTableID = UserTableID
                };
                ViewBag.newdomain = newclient;
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try out the suggestion mentioned in the error message? 
like this?

```
 csv.configuration.HeaderValidated = null;
```

Comment: @ah yes! sorry that did fix that though I have a new problem now haha, thank you

Comment: you're welcome, it's always worth double checking the error messages and hope that the developer took some time writing meaningful error messages ;-)

Answer (score 9):

[The developer made some breaking changes this year](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/1651), so the accepted answer will no longer work.

Instead, you have to create a configuration object in advance and inject it in the constructor:

```
var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
  {
     HeaderValidated = null
  };
using (var reader = new StreamReader(file))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
```

Answer (score 5):

Make sure to include both these lines:

```
csv.Configuration.HeaderValidated = null;

csv.Configuration.MissingFieldFound = null;
```

Answer (score -1):

The accepted answer will no longer work as per the changes made by the developer which makes it mandatory to add required CultureInfo parameter to any class that uses CultureInfo.

**Change Log:** https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/change-log/

Hence, going forward first you have to create a CSV configuration and inject it in the constructor as below:

```
var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
  {
     HeaderValidated = null,
     MissingFieldFound = null
  };
using (var reader = new StreamReader(file))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
```

**NOTE:** It's mandatory to set both the above configurations to null